# Call Joomla Native Language Title

Tags: template-override, multilingual

The site uses a custom mod_menu. How do you call the native language title?

```
<?php

    $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
    $lang_name = $lang->getName(); 

?>

    <?php echo $lang_name;?>
```

This returns:
English (en-GB) or for Chinese: "中文(繁體．台灣)".

However - I want the native title which is "EN".

Or for Chinese the Native Title is "繁中".

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
  <?php
        $app             = JFactory::getApplication();
        $doc             = JFactory::getDocument();
        $this->language  = $doc->language;
        $lng=explode('-',$this->language);
        print(strtoupper($lng[0]));
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks - I adapted it to as it was causing a php error:

<?php
 $app  = JFactory::getApplication();
        $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
        $language  = $doc->language;
        $lng=explode('-',$language);
        print(strtoupper($lng[0]));
 ?>

However - this isn't pulling the native title - just the doc->language. So - it fails with the multi-linguial version. Eg Chinese 中文 becomes ZH.